# Flyback transformer (BSC25 T1010A) pinout

Tags: transformer, flyback, pinout

I have a flyback transformer (BSC25 T1010A) with a pinout I attached below, but I don't know what the names of the pins represent (TP1, TP2, B+115, H.out, HT).

I need to find the primary and flyback pins in a flyback transformer. I want to know how much input voltage can be given to the flyback.

[image: Flyback transformer]

Answer (score 1):

Flyback are usually replacement parts for tv/monitors, so rarely would you get a datasheet. From what is shown, my guess is B+115V is the voltage source and h.out (col) goes to the horizontal output transistor collector. This transistor switches the circuit to 0V. For something more definitive, find out which TV/monitor this item is for and hopefully you can find a schematic.